How to get string length without ANSI escape sequences?
I have a script that generates a string containing ANSI escape codes. I want to centralize this string, for which I need to know its length without ANSI codes.
CSI = '\033[';

X = f'{ CSI }0m';
R = f'{ CSI }91m';
G = f'{ CSI }92m';
B = f'{ CSI }94m';
C = f'{ CSI }96m';
M = f'{ CSI }95m';
Y = f'{ CSI }93m';
K = f'{ CSI }90m';

# ...

tc = 100; # terminal columns
tl = 10; # terminal lines
mc = 200; # message columns
ml = 20; # message lines

msg = f'Size{K}:{X} {tc} {K}x{X} {tl} {K}/{X} Min size{K}:{X} {mc} {K}x{X} {ml}';

The script above will generate a message Size: 100 x 10 / Min size: 200 x 20 with certain parts of it being colored using ANSI escape sequences. String length without ANSI codes is 35, however len(msg) will return 80.
Note: this is a simplified example. In reality variables tc, tl, mc, ml are not static.
This question is similar to "How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python".
However, it is about getting a string length without ANSI sequences. The most obvious solution to this is to remove ANSI codes from the string and then get its length. But I posed the question the way I did, because I was not sure that this is the only way to do it. Maybe at least on some systems the string length is stored somewhere.
If the only way to get string length without ANSI codes is to remove them, then I'm going to use a different method than provided as an answer to the other question. I'm reluctant to use a non built-in function that removes all ANSI codes using a regular expression. In my example I have only a few CSI commands that I'm using and I'd rather write a function that removes just these codes.
def get_rid_of_asci(msg: str, ansi: list) -> str:

    for code in ansi:

        msg = msg.replace(code, '')

    return msg

msg_clean = get_rid_of_asci(msg, [ R, G, B, C, M, Y, K, X ])

print(len(msg)) # 80
print(len(msg_clean)) # 35


Unfortunatelly, that is only possible if you parse the ansi sequences to remove then from the string. This parsing has been on my  private roadmap to my "terminedia"  terminal framework - feel free to add an explicit issue there at github.com/jsbueno/terminedia

To make pretty text, check out https://github.com/Textualize/rich if you haven't already

You will have to remove the escape sequences (see the duplicate) from your string, then get the length of what remains.

As I posted in the O.P. comment: you would have to parse the ANSI sequences out of a string in order to know its length. I know of no ready-made library which could parse all possible sequences, and they can be of varying lengths, accepting multiple parameters per sequence.
Another approach would be to calculate positioning before  adding ANSI sequences for coloring or other effects - and this is what libraries and frameworks working on the terminal do.
Depending on what you plan to do, you could use the "terminedia" framework (disclaimer: I am the author) - it can create a screen abstraction with the Screen class  which allows for separate attribute setting of each character cell, for example, as well as coordinate (x,y)  positioning of text, and picking the write-direction.
You can install terminedia with pip install terminedia.
There are few docs, and they are mostly extracted from the doc-strings of the classes themselves - you can check those for more than basic usage.

In what sense are you "disclaiming"? Did you mean disclosure?
